# Android - saving user operation steps

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, refactoring

In my applicaition there are some user operation which have severeal steps. For example

1 - Type your name and surname

2 - Type your credit cart number

3 - Type your address

.

.

we are saving the steps  in to local database to let the user can continue later. Because users can cancel it when ever they want.

I wonder which kind of pattern i can use in this screnario.

(I am asking about software architecture)

Comment: There is no special pattern for this, but more important no sensitive user data should be saved on user phone. Maybe phone is rooted so any app could get this data and .. Hopefully you did not stay with this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion. If possible use [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) for the user input. That will automatically preserve last state. SO that you won't need to store in database at each step. Then save the data only in final step.

And another personal opinion is, you shouldn't preserve important data like credit card info before final step

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually i asked about software architecture, do you have an opinion about which pattern (visitor,factory,command ...) is good for this screnarion ?

Comment: "you shouldn't preserve important data like credit card info before final step", so are you saying that without address credit card number is no use for developer or I misunderstood? :) I did not actually got it how this is dependent. Basically NONE of such a sensitive data of the user should be saved on his (maybe rooted) phone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what kind of pattern you're looking for.

If you want to user to go through these steps, probably the best UI design would be a wizard as described by Roman Nurik: https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6cVymZvn3f4

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually i asked about software architecture, do you have an opinion about which pattern (visitor,factory,command ...) is good for this screnarion ?

Comment: No, I would not now of any design pattern which would have anything to do with what you described. All you're describing is giving the user 1 or more screens to ask for some data input...

Comment: Suggested UI pattern fits nice here and I agree there is no need for design pattern. This was overthinking IMHO.